# How to create and deploy a ColdFusion JEE archive?

Tags: tomcat, coldfusion, war

I'm trying to package my ColdFusion application into a WAR file to be deployed on Tomcat, and I think something is going wrong when I create the archive.

In ColdFusion administrator I added a new JEE archive, selected my application directory (which includes subdirectories for the source, javascripts, graphics, etc.), chose the WAR file option, and included my datasource. After clicking submit, it created the WAR file and I deployed it to Tomcat but was unable to start the application (error pasted below). I checked inside the WAR file and it just contains all of my CFML source and everything else, no jsp or class files at all.

Does anyone know what I could be doing wrong here?

This is the error I'm getting from Tomcat when I try to start the application:

```
-Mar-2021 13:49:04.286 SEVERE [30] org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log HTMLManager: Error starting [/C:ColdFusion2021cfusionpackagesAPDAPD]
org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Error starting the loader
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappLoader.startInternal(WebappLoader.java:402)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:4977)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.manager.ManagerServlet.start(ManagerServlet.java:1396)
    at org.apache.catalina.manager.HTMLManagerServlet.start(HTMLManagerServlet.java:703)
    at org.apache.catalina.manager.HTMLManagerServlet.doPost(HTMLManagerServlet.java:223)
    at jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:689)
    at jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:770)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:223)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:158)
    at org.apache.catalina.filters.CsrfPreventionFilter.doFilter(CsrfPreventionFilter.java:211)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:185)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:158)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:185)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:158)
    at org.apache.catalina.filters.HttpHeaderSecurityFilter.doFilter(HttpHeaderSecurityFilter.java:126)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:185)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:158)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:668)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.RequestFilterValve.process(RequestFilterValve.java:378)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.RemoteAddrValve.invoke(RemoteAddrValve.java:56)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:690)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:353)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:374)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:870)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1696)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: javax.management.MalformedObjectNameException: Invalid character ':' in value part of property
    at javax.management.ObjectName.construct(Unknown Source)
    at javax.management.ObjectName.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappLoader.startInternal(WebappLoader.java:395)
    ... 38 more
```

Comment: You probably have a `:` character in the name of the WAR file.

Comment: I wish it were such a simple issue, but the name of the file is TestWAR.war

Comment: You are trying to run the application on Tomcat 10 (as indicated by the `jakarta.servlet` package prefix). I doubt ColdFusion supports Servlet 5.0, try with Tomcat 9.0.

Comment: I installed Tomcat 9.0 and deployed the file again, but I'm still getting the same error when I try to run it. I think something must be going wrong when I create the archive. I set it to not include the source code, but all of my source code ends up in the WAR file unchanged. Shouldn't ColdFusion be compiling these into java bytecode? According to this: https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/configuring-administering/deploying-coldfusion-applications.ug.html#PackagingapplicationsinJ2EEarchivefiles